# Custom data in signature dictionary using itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Im trying to add custom data to a signature field (in the end this can be anything from biometrics to informational).

```
PdfFormField signatureField = stamper.AddSignature(
    signingBlock.Name, signingBlock.Page,
    signingBlock.X, signingBlock.Y, signingBlock.X + signingBlock.Width,
    signingBlock.Y + signingBlock.Height);
signatureField.Put(new PdfName("SomeRandomKey"), new PdfString("Some random text goes here"));
```

But since playing with this, ive inspected the PDF structure and the values are never stored in a document. What would be the appropriate way to add custom data to a signature field, it has to be specific tot he signature field because I'm catering for multiple signatures, hence I cant use the /Info dictionary.

Any help would be appreciated.
Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stamper.AddSignature` is a convenience method which

- creates a new PDF form field,
- sets signature parameters according to the parameters,
- creates an appearance,
- references this form field from the interactive form and the page annotation dictionaries, and
- **writes the form field PDF objects to the output stream/file**!

Thus, the information you add to the object you retrieve from that method is added too late.

The method is implemented like this:

```
virtual public PdfFormField AddSignature(String name, int page, float llx, float lly, float urx, float ury) {
    PdfAcroForm acroForm = stamper.AcroForm;
    PdfFormField signature = PdfFormField.CreateSignature(stamper);
    acroForm.SetSignatureParams(signature, name, llx, lly, urx, ury);
    acroForm.DrawSignatureAppearences(signature, llx, lly, urx, ury);
    AddAnnotation(signature, page);
    return signature;
}
```

The `AddAnnotation` call implicitly writes the form field object to stream/file.

Instead of calling it like you did, therefore, you may want to do something like this:

```
PdfAcroForm acroForm = stamper.Writer.AcroForm;
PdfFormField signature = PdfFormField.CreateSignature(stamper.Writer);
acroForm.SetSignatureParams(signature, signingBlock.Name, signingBlock.X, signingBlock.Y, signingBlock.X + signingBlock.Width, signingBlock.Y + signingBlock.Height);
acroForm.DrawSignatureAppearences(signature, signingBlock.X, signingBlock.Y, signingBlock.X + signingBlock.Width, signingBlock.Y + signingBlock.Height);

signature.Put(new PdfName("SomeRandomKey"), new PdfString("Some random text goes here"));

stamper.AddAnnotation(signature, signingBlock.Page);
```

Comment: so that solves the problem i was having. But wont the same problem exist for existing signature blocks? i.e. trying to add values to the dictionary?

Kind regards

Comment: You can open the file in a `PdfReader`, manipulate the PDF objects, and store the manipulated PDF using a `PdfStamper`. If you use *append mode*, please mark the changed objects as *used* using `PdfStamper.MarkUsed` .

Comment: Awesome i see that what i was missing was the MarkUsed part :) Thank you mkl you're a champ man :D 

Kind Regards